# Is there a way I can batch Auto Smooth hundreds of objects?

Tags: scripting, objects, workflow

I have well over a hundred objects in Asset Management folders that I need to set as smooth and then set Auto Smooth to 40 degrees. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this so I don't have to touch each .blend file separately?

Comment: Are you on windows or unix type?